# Copy specific table data from one database to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I need to copy specific data from select set of tables in one SQL Server to another SQL Server. Any pointers to this will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the inputs. I created linked servers and using this i was able to move data from one database to other. But now, my team is saying that linked servers are not allowed because of security restrictions. Also i was not able to use openrowset due to policy restrictions. So anyother way to do the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Create a linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998%28v=bts.70%29.aspx) or use Openrowset to create a connection with remote server.

use linked server if you need to perform routine task with remote server else use openrowset.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

[See this also](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/how-do-i-query-foreign-data-using-sql-servers-linked-servers/133)

Answer (score 1):

There's also the SSIS wizard, aka [SQL Server Import/Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)  Instead of full table copies, specify the source queries, save to disk (assuming you'll need to re-run the process periodically) and voila, data copy in a box

Answer (score 0):

Use a linked server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can move data to another table, or you can create a table based on the other table. Your question is a good one that I have heard before so I wrote a quick [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnsoldevs/archive/2011/09/06/how-to-move-data-from-one-table-to-another.aspx) explaining the options

Answer (score 0):

you can copy data from one database to another.
The mysql query is:

```
insert into database2.table_name2(field name) 
select table_name1.field_name from table_name1 
    where table_name1.field_name = condition
```

The above mysql query is used for copy specific data between databases.
Suppose you want to copy whole table datd, then you will use following query:

```
insert into database2.table_name2(field name) 
select table_name1.field_name from table_name1
```